# Bubble Effect on image (Photoshop or online)

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, effect, image-manipulation, fisheye

I have a square image (300 x 300), and I'd like to apply the "bubble effect" as shown here:

[image]

Specifically:

- I only want the "bubble" part in this example
- Make image round and give it that curved effect
- Make the edges softer/blurred

How can I do this?
I'm either looking for a solution in Photoshop, or an online tool that can do this for me.

Comment: What makes you think that wasn't captured that way to begin with?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I'm asking: if I captured a normal photo, is it possible to do something to make it look like that?

Comment: Yeah it's called a fish eye effect. Usually we try to remove it, but it can be added as well. I'm pretty sure the example photo has been flipped upside-down and colors adjusted, but I think the image in the glass was captured that way. A glass sphere IS a fish-eye lense.

Comment: Get a mirrorless camera, find a lens that's made for a smaller format than your mirrorless camera (C-mount?) and shoot away. Crop and edit out in a photo editor if you want it round.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in Photoshop, you'll need Photoshop's **Spherize** filter traditionally located under Filters -> Distort -> Spherize.

First, use the selection (marquee) tool for selecting circles, make sure you select a perfect circle.  Copy this circle to a new image or layer.  Now, on this selection, run the Spherize filter at 100%.

[image]

Example result (here the effect was on the layer with the green text, but the principle is the same for a photo; apply the effect to a perfect circular selection of photo).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial of how to replicate the "fish eye" effect...

http://www.creativebloq.com/photoshop/recreate-fish-eye-effect-11121244

Comment: Please add a summary of the contents of that article here, or this answer becomes useless when the link dues in a couple of years.

Comment: OK sure, no problem I'll do that a bit later today.

Comment: Or later the next month :)

Comment: Or not at all...